# Display Local database c#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, adapter

I have a probnlem displaying what's in my Database table. I've followed my class instructions but I've been stuck for 2 days without success!

Here is what I've done so far;

```
string conStr = @"Data Source=C:\Users\secwp_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Module5\Module5\Orderdatabase.sdf";


SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Order", con);
SqlCeDataAdapter adapt = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(ds, "Order");

foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
       {
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
       }
    }
}
```

When i run the code i get a error on `adapt.Fill(ds, "Order");` saying `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`. Which I don't really understand.

EDIT: My DataConnections is;

```
Data Connections
    Orderdatabase.sdf
        Tables
            Order
                Columns
                    OrderID
                    etc..
```

Adding output for Nicks solution:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 21,Token in error = Order ]
   vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
   vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
   vid System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   vid System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(Command Behavior behavior)
   vid System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable [] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String, srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   vid System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(Dataset dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   vid System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable)
   vid Module5.Program.Main(String[] args) i c:\Users\secwp_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Module5\Module5\Program.cs:rad 54
```

EDIT: Here is a picture of what it looks like atm. http://oi61.tinypic.com/9pq70l.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the stacktrace exactly? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I've never encountred that word. So I don't know.

Comment: Try putting a try catch statement around your adapt.fill. In your catch statement put your e into a message box and it will give you more information about your error. Also as a silly little thing: Are you sure that your table Order is with a capital letter in your database? Silly mistake but I've made it many times.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post images, but in the server explorer under tables the table is named "Order". I don't know what to write after catch, we have barley worked with that.

Comment: use it like this: try { adapt.fill(ds, "Order"); } catch (Exception e) {Messagebox.Show(e.toString());}

Comment: @NickOtten I added  

try { adapt.Fill(ds, "Order"); }
            catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e); }

And I get output, but with alot of Errors and text.

Comment: That lots of errors and text is your stack trace. could you add it to your question? it contains the information we need to help you out.

Comment: @NickOtten I'll write it all down and post it in my question.

Comment: use System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(e.toString()) instead of the the messagebox.show. It will put your stacktrace on your clipboard so you can paste it here.

Comment: @NickOtten Oh my god, i should have read that before I started..

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the order table supposed to be plural?

Ex. SELECT * FROM ORDERS

Comment: @JamesShaw I can name the table whatever I want. But Orders is more corret. The table is holding Orders, when they are ordered, to where and from its shipped, price etc.

Comment: I realize that, I was asking if you happen to be using it singularly when it should be plural or vice versa.

Comment: Hmpf sqlCE gives pretty bad stacktraces. doesn't contain any info at all. I did a quick look over the internet about sqlCE and noticed that they used spaces in there connection strings. Would be bad if this solved it but try: string conStr = @"Data Source = C:\Users\secwp_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Module5\Module5\Orderdatabase.sdf";

Comment: Per your stack trace, the issue is in the parsing of the query.

Comment: @JamesShaw I'm using "Order" everywhere. I added a picture if that helps.

Comment: @NickOtten Same result. Is there anything i could take a screenshot of to make it all more clear of what could be wrong? My own guess is that the database doesnt exist or is connected somehow. But at the same time i have no idea.

Comment: Have a look at the following:
http://chalaki.com/using-sqlcedataadapater-and-sqlcedataset-to-modify-data-in-sql-server-ce-tables/224/

Perhaps it will shed some light.

Comment: @Oscar Yes I think it must be something with the connection. Your code seems fine in the picture that you linked. The stacktrace is also inconclusive. the result you get there in sqlCE's way of saying "Well I don't know!" and could literally mean anything. You can test if the connection is working by trying to get the database schema with getShema() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802050(v=vs.100).aspx . You have to place it after the con.open(). You can put the result into a Datatable and write that to a datagridview ( datagridview.setDatasource(con.getSchema()); )

Comment: @JamesShaw Thank you James, seems very helpful! I have to eat now, but i will come back in a couple of hours. Hopefully with results :) And thanks to all other for helping. I need a short break, and I'll get back into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose the table name in brackets, as this is a reserved Word:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [Order]", con);
```

And using SELECT * is never a good idea

Answer (score 0):

First of all SELECT * from Order is a huge collection of data, I suggest you try this:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
        using(con)
        {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT OrderID FROM Order", con);
        string OrderID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(OrderID);
        }
```

And if this is successful then go on to execute using foreach to access all rows and columns using `SELECT * FROM ORDER`

Comment: I get "ExecuteScalar requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is Closed." Im guessing the database isnt connected somehow? :S

Comment: using (con) { con.Open(); string orderID = cmd.executeScaler().ToString(); }

Comment: @NickOtten With that coderow i get a error on "...string orderID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();.."  saying "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll"

Comment: @SandySands That type or namespace couldnt be found. I can only write SqlCeCommand

Comment: Namespace : System.Data.SqlClient and also add in the Reference Framework and in Reference Extension

Comment: @SandySands Says ExecuteScalar needs a connections, which is closed. Don't know what that means.

Comment: string conStr = @"Data Source=C:\Users\secwp_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Module5\Module5\Orderdatabase.sdf" is errorneous. That is why.

Comment: Try using SSMS SQL to create DBs and input values using the code

Comment: @SandySands Iv'e had my eays on that and tried different things but nothing changes. 

Should it be something like 
`code`string conStr = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Orderdatabase.sdf";`code` ?

And the computer/program finds the batabase by itself? I'm really confused..

Comment: @SandySands In the excercise im doing i'm not allowed to insert values from code.. I thought the same 2 days ago :)

Comment: Your not, this is just select. Open SSMS, select File->Open->Files, navigate to your folder, open the file, save it in an existing DB, then goto Appconfig of your Solution, and add: <add name="conStr" connectionString="Data Source =*server_name*;Initial Catalog =*DB_Name*;User Id = *Username*;Password = *Password*"/>

Comment: @SandySands What i meant was that I'm not allowed to even create teh Table from code, I must do it from "Create a simple 
database in Console Application". If this doesnt answer that you just wrote, i'm to much of a noob.. Sorry.